# Prove that a given block matrix is symmetric indefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

> Let matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric positive definite and let fat matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m<n$, have full row rank. Let \begin{equation}\mathcal{C}=\begin{bmatrix}A&B^T\\B&0\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation} Prove that block matrix $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric indefinite.

---

I have been able to show the symmetry of the given matrix as follows:

When taking a tranpose of a block matrix we must also tranpose each individual block, but note that $A$ is SPD, hence $A^T=A$;

\begin{equation}\mathcal{C}^T=\begin{bmatrix}A^T&B^T\\(B^T)^T&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A&B^T\\B&0\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}

and hence $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C}^T$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is symmetric.

However, I do not know how to show the indefiniteness of this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x^T & y^T \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A&B^T\\B&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = x^TAx + x^TB^Ty +y^TBx = x^TAx + 2y^TBx.
$$

We know that when $y = 0$ and $x \neq 0$, we have $x^TAx > 0$. So all we need to do is argue that this expression can also be negative.

Note that $B$ has full row rank means that $y^TB = 0$ if and only if $y = 0$.

So pick an $x$ not in the kernel of $B$ and then look at the function
$$f(y) = y^TBx.$$
Argue that you can make this sufficiently negative to make the whole expression at the top negative.

Comment: Is the arguement at the end as simple as stating "We can choose some $y$ such that it satisfied" or am I missing something.

Comment: @Debby The first step was making sure there is some choice of $x, y$ for which $y^TBx \neq 0$. Afterwards, $f(ty) = tf(y)$ and you can make this whatever you want for an appropriate choice of $t$.

Comment: I am still getting a bit confused here, I understand up to the point where we have that we dont want $y=0$ so that $y^TB\neq 0$ and we are choosing $x\in$ ker$(B)$ so that $Bx\neq 0$. I am getting confused specifically at the choice we can make

Comment: @Debby Take any $y \neq 0$ then $y^TB \neq 0$. Then take $x = (y^TB)^T$ so $y^TBx = x^Tx \neq 0$. That's all you need is just a non-zero value.

Comment: Sorry I am not geting confused at the choice of $x$, its the choice of y in the very last arguement so that the whole expression at the top becomes negative

Comment: @Debby If $y^TBx$ is say $7$ then $(-100y)^TBx = -700$. Just look at the line spanned by $y$.

Comment: So it is sufficient to simply state for the final arguement "We can choose a $y$ such that the expression is negative"?

Comment: @Debby Or you could solve $x^TAx + 2(ty)^TBx = -1$ for $t$. Word the argument in the way that you like.